# It is possible to create grouped charts in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have many variables with the same time scale, Is there any way to create a grouped chart in Excel?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: not by default.  You could manually arrange 3 separate graph to line up and sit on top of one another, but there is nothing built in that automatically does it as far as I know.

Comment: @Roga Lu, once I've had created Column Chart in group for Weekly data. First Convert Data into Table so that Excel will automatically include chart for New Group. Then Select data and choose Clustered Column Chart type.

Comment: @Roga Lu,, another is Create Pivot Table Chart after you group the data. Hope either methods will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no built in automatic way to do this.  Manually and with a little bit of eyeballing it, you can achieve the following:
[image]

This is actually three separate graphs placed one above the other with a few things turned on and off and and a little bit of sideways stretching by eye to get the vertical gridlines to align.  Even after doing this, there are a few problems.

1. The vertical gridlines are not perfectly aligned
2. The values of the Y-axis overlap and cause a reading issue.
3. Series legend cannot be at the bottom for all three graphs or even together unless you do a little trickery
4. your time scales limits (X-axis) need to be the same for all graphs
5. There can be nothing behind the graphs as the graph backgrounds are transparent
6. The graphs cannot be placed on their own tab, they need to stay on a worksheet
7. **you need to check repeatedly that the graphs remain vertically aligned as they are subject to dynamic changes in scales as data, series' names change**

   If this manual method works for you I can expand on the answer in order to achieve similar results.